# Pandas Date Range Monthly on Specific Day of Month

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

In Pandas, I know you can use anchor offsets to specify more complicated reucrrences:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offset

I want to specify a date_range such that it is monthly on the nth day of each month. What is the best syntax to do that with? I'm imaginging something similar to this which specifies a recurrence every 2 weeks on Friday:

```
schedule = pd.date_range(start=START_STR, periods=26, freq="2W-FRI")
```

Comment: Even if there is not a ready-made `pandas` function to do this, you should be able to write a simple helper function to do this `pd.date_range` and `pd.DatetimeIndex`. Take a look at [my sample script](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gt4t8232vupow79/monthly_date_range.py?dl=0).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
In [18]: pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2016-01-01', periods=10, freq='MS') + pd.DateOffset(days=26), columns=['Date'])
Out[18]:
        Date
0 2016-01-27
1 2016-02-27
2 2016-03-27
3 2016-04-27
4 2016-05-27
5 2016-06-27
6 2016-07-27
7 2016-08-27
8 2016-09-27
9 2016-10-27
```

**UPDATE:**  to account for different numbers of days of months and leap years:

```
def month_range(start, periods=12):
    rng = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp(start)-pd.offsets.MonthBegin(),
                        periods=periods,
                        freq='MS')
    ret = (rng + pd.offsets.Day(pd.Timestamp(start).day-1)).to_series()
    ret.loc[ret.dt.month > rng.month] -= pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1)
    return pd.DatetimeIndex(ret)
```

---

Examples:

```
In [202]: month_range('2016-01-27', 12)
Out[202]:
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-27', '2016-02-27', '2016-03-27', '2016-04-27', '2016-05-27', '2016-06-27', '2016-07-27', '2016-08-27',
               '2016-09-27', '2016-10-27', '2016-11-27', '2016-12-27'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

In [203]: month_range('2020-01-31', 12)
Out[203]:
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-31', '2020-02-29', '2020-03-31', '2020-04-30', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-30', '2020-07-31', '2020-08-31',
               '2020-09-30', '2020-10-31', '2020-11-30', '2020-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

In [204]: month_range('2019-01-29', 12)
Out[204]:
DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-29', '2019-02-28', '2019-03-29', '2019-04-29', '2019-05-29', '2019-06-29', '2019-07-29', '2019-08-29',
               '2019-09-29', '2019-10-29', '2019-11-29', '2019-12-29'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Neat solution, but does not account for different numbers of days for each month and leap years, e.g. for a day offset of 29 or higher.

Comment: @mloning, thank you for pointing it out - I tried to improve my answer...

Answer (score 3):

No need to re-invent the wheel. Use `DateOffset` from pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
from datetime import date

date1 = date(2019,1,29)
pd.date_range(date1, periods=12, freq=DateOffset(months=1))
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-29', '2019-02-28', '2019-03-28', '2019-04-28',
               '2019-05-28', '2019-06-28', '2019-07-28', '2019-08-28',
               '2019-09-28', '2019-10-28', '2019-11-28', '2019-12-28'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='<DateOffset: months=1>')
```

Comment: But once it's reduced to 28, rest of the dates are also 28. Same happens with 31. If its Jan 31 then rest of the months gets reduced to 28

Comment: pd.date_range(date1, periods=12, freq=pd.DateOffset(months=1))

Answer (score 1):

Edit: The accepted answer did initially not account for different numbers of days of months and leap years. Here's still an alternative function to solve the problem:

```
import pandas as pd

def month_range_day(start=None, periods=None):
    start_date = pd.Timestamp(start).date()
    month_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, periods=periods, freq='M')
    month_day = month_range.day.values
    month_day[start_date.day < month_day] = start_date.day
    return pd.to_datetime(month_range.year*10000+month_range.month*100+month_day, format='%Y%m%d')
```

**Example 1**:

```
start_date = '2020-01-31'
month_range_day(start=start_date, periods=12)
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-31', '2020-02-29', '2020-03-31', '2020-04-30',
               '2020-05-31', '2020-06-30', '2020-07-31', '2020-08-31',
               '2020-09-30', '2020-10-31', '2020-11-30', '2020-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

**Example 2:**

```
start_date = '2019-01-29'
month_range_day(start=start_date, periods=12)
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-29', '2019-02-28', '2019-03-29', '2019-04-29',
               '2019-05-29', '2019-06-29', '2019-07-29', '2019-08-29',
               '2019-09-29', '2019-10-29', '2019-11-29', '2019-12-29'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```